# Get Qt running on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I wanted to set up Qt so I could develop applications with it. It all seemed pretty straight forward - i ran the installer and it installed. I then added the path variable to /etc/profile. the qmake -v command works as described in the netbeans docs, but netbeans does not seem to detect the include files required for Qt.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You've told NetBeans where `qmake` is, but you haven't told it where Qt's source files are.

Comment: How do I tell it where the source files are?

Comment: Try launching the Configure Code Assistance wizard by right-clicking the project and choosing Code Assistance -> Configure Code Assistance

Comment: This option seems to be grayed out for me :( http://f.cl.ly/items/1q0F311F3T3x0C0F0J16/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-17%20at%2012.23.29.png

Comment: You might have to turn off 'C/C++ Code Assistance' first.  This is a NetBeans problem, not a Qt problem - so if NetBeans has a support forum, you might be better off asking there.

Comment: I think i got it working, I tried running the program, pointed it towards my QtSDK directory and it ran. I still get the squiggly lines under the include statement.

Comment: I recommend just using QtCreator, in my experience it's just as good as NetBeans as an IDE, but works with Qt far better.

Comment: It's all working now, after running the application for the first time, netbeans asked for the qmake command directory. I pointed it towards that and it was all working perfectly after a project cleanup. I still prefer netbeans over the QTCreator, just because the QTCreator is by nokia and was designed for one specific purpose and Netbeans wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup I fixed it:
If you are getting those errors, add the qmake command to your path variable, reboot your computer and then attempt to run the basic QT project in netbeans. It should prompt for a qmake directory. Point that towards QT's bin folder and the project should run. For the the squiggly lines disappeared after a project cleanup.